# When is an interval (order theory) = line segment (in $\mathbb{R}^n$)?

Tags: convex-analysis, order-theory

If $(X,\leq)$ is any [poset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poset) and $a,b\!\in\!X$, then we define the *interval* as 
$$[a,b]_\leq:=\{x\!\in\!X;\;a\!\leq\!x\!\leq\!b\}.$$

If $a,b\!\in\!\mathbb{R}^n$, then we define the *line segment* as 
$$[a,b]_{\mathbb{R}^n}:=\{a\!+\!t(b\!-\!a);\;t\!\in\![0,1]\}.$$

A subset $A\!\subseteq\!X$ is called *convex* when $\forall a,a'\!\in\!A\!:[a,a']_\leq\!\subseteq A$.

A subset $A\!\subseteq\!\mathbb{R}^n$ is called *convex* when $\forall a,a'\!\in\!A\!:[a,a']_{\mathbb{R}^n}\!\subseteq A$.

**Question:** how can I define a partial ordering $\leq$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $\forall a,b\!\in\!\mathbb{R}^n\!:[a,b]_\leq=[a,b]_{\mathbb{R}^n}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, for $n\geq 2$. The endwise joining of intervals $[a,b]_{\leq}$ and $[b,c]_{\leq}$ is again an interval $[a,c]_{\leq}$, but even if $[a,b]_\leq=[a,b]_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ and $[b,c]_\leq=[b,c]_{\mathbb{R}^n}$, their union need not be a line segment if $b$ doesn't lie on a line through $a,c$.

Comment: Of course, you're right. Too bad. thanks

Comment: Glad I could help.